# Link to tab from different page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

We are working on a Bootstrap website to present our schoolwork. I have a fair understanding of the used html code, but I am having one problem.

To link to a specific tab/section within a page this link is used:

```
href="#tab"
```

I have copied the original index.html and thus created a second webpage. I'm able to link to this page using:

```
href="page2.html"
```

But I'm not able to link directly to a tab/section on that second page. I tried using `href="page2.html/#tab"` or `"page2.html#tab"` etc. But it doesn't work yet, I think I miss some fundamental knowledge about this coding.

Could anyone explain me how to get this working, in 'normal' language. There are several (older) solutions, but can't get them to work in the javascript files.

Comment: Fixed tags, improved formatting and removed tag from title. java is different from javascript please tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should help...

http://codepen.io/mattsince87/pen/exByn

LINK -> `<a id="link1" class="nav-section1" href="#section1">S1. Info</a>`

Content -> `<h1 id="section1">1. Info</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this as i have this thing running in my project. these will check the page if it contains the tabs then it will take the last value from the url of the page2 and will make it visible.

```
if($("#tabs").length)
{
    var id = window.location.hash.substr(1);    
    $('#tabs a[href="#'+id+'"]').tab('show');
}
```